# Calling single db connection using static method

Tags: php, pdo

I tried to follow the structure factory in creating a single db connection as per below:

```
try {
    $provider = function() {
        $instance = new PDO("dsn", "username", "password");
        return $instance;
    }; 
} catch (PDOException $exception) {
    error_log($exception->getMessage());
}
$factory = new StructureFactory($provider);
```

and StructureFactory as below:

```
class StructureFactory {
    protected $provider = null;
    protected $connection = null;

    public function __construct(callable $provider) {
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }

    public function create($class_name) {
        if ($this->connection === null) {
            $this->connection = call_user_func($this->provider);
        }
        return new $class_name($this->connection);
    }
}
```

Then when I need to create a book instance, say "Book", I do this:

```
$factory->create("Book");
```

But if I don't need to create a book instance yet but just want to check if that book is existing, I'd like to call a static method on my "Book" class like:

```
Book::isBookExisting($bookname);
```

But inside this static method, how can I have the single database connection if I can only have it when I create the "Book" instance?

Or should I just use a Singleton for my db connection instead of doing this factory?

I am kinda at lost cause I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly.  Please advise.

Comment: Or why not just pass your Object into your method? then return it when its finished (if you want to use the updated one) either that or global the object.

Comment: I just put it that way for simplicity :)

Answer (score 0):

## First

The way you've written the `try` `catch` block is mostly useless and certainly not doing as you expect.

```
try {
    $provider = function() {
        $instance = new PDO("dsn", "username", "password");
        return $instance;
    }; 
} catch (PDOException $exception) {
    error_log($exception->getMessage());
}
```

Remember, `$provider = function() { ...` is an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). The code inside it only runs when the function is called. In other words, the code inside the `try` block, in your example, will *never* throw an exception. It will only ever throw an exception when is is called e.g. `$provider()`.

## Refactored

```
$provider = function() {
    try {
        $instance = new PDO("dsn", "username", "password");
    } catch (PDOException $exception) {
        error_log($exception->getMessage());
    }
    return $instance;
};
```

## The database connection

There are too many ways to solve the database dependency issue, many of which are opinionated. There is no one solution.

You could:

- Use a singleton
- Use a argument dep. `Book::isBookExisting($provider, $bookname);`
- Use a static dep. `Book::setProvider($provider); Book::isBookExisting($bookname);`
- ...

Further Reading:

- [Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dependency+injection)